# Use Apache yarn to manage C++ applications

Tags: hadoop-yarn

Yarn uses container to manage resource for an application. For example, a container defines the allocated memory/CPU cores for an application. How does this work with C++ applications? Given a container with some resource, like 512MB, 2 CPUs, how can the C++ application obey it or be contained?

For java applications, is the resource containment done by confining the resource of the jvm of the java application?

Answer (score 0):

Yarn restricts the memory usage of the containers by monitoring the child process and killing it if it exceeds the allowed limit.

When you spawn a C++ application with Yarn, the NodeManager starts a child process and begins to monitor the process. If look into the NodeManger's local logs, you see a lot of logs on the memory usage of the child process. If the child process exceeds the allowed limit (by default, a container can use 2x the amount of memory it claimed, which can be configured), it kills the process. The same applies to both C++ applications and Java applications.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop uses Linux CGroups to put bounds on container's resource usage. As of release 2.7.2, YARN containers provide bounds only on CPU utilization. [Reference](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeManagerCgroups.html)